# How to use execvpe() in C correctly?

Tags: c, process

I am trying to run the compiled C code using `execvpe()` function in C. My code file is located at `/code/Solution.c`. I compiled it using the command `gcc /code/Solution.c -o /code/Solution`. I want to run the compiled code, i.e, the `/code/Solution` file using `execvpe()`. When I run it manually I use the command `./code/Solution < /input/1.txt &> /stdout/1.txt` and it works perfectly but it gets stuck(the program never ends) when I try to do the same programmatically using `execvpe()`. Following is my code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    char *args[] = {"./Solution", "<", "/input/1.txt", "&>", "/stdout/1.txt", NULL};
    char *env[]  = {"PATH=/code", NULL};
    int x = execvpe("Solution", args, env);
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post code as text rather than pictures.

Comment: Ref [execvpe(3) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvpe).

Comment: `"./Solution", "<", "/input/1.txt", "&>", "/stdout/1.txt` needs to go though command processing.  Example: `"<"` is not the first arg to `"./Solution"`.

Comment: The pipe is the shell's symbol, not actually a low-level command.

Comment: @chux I am not getting what you are trying to say

Comment: When you do in shell `./code/Solution < /input/1.txt &> /stdout/1.txt` you run a program from `./code/Solution` with __no arguments__ with stdin binded from /input/1.txt file and stdout and stderr binded to /stdout/1.txt. You can recreate that with `fork` + `dup` and `exec`. With execvpe you can run /bin/sh with proper arguments `{"-c", "\"./code/Solution < .... \""}` or you need to call `dup`  to bind your stdout and stderr and stdin and then call execvpe.

Comment: @chux I don't believe the program name is the problem. The absolute paths on the other hand...

Comment: @KamilCuk can you please explain or refer something. I am pretty much inexperienced in this part of C programming.

Comment: It's not C, it's your shell. See [POSIX shell manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07) section 2.7.1. and 2.7.2. and the whole redirection section. The `&>` is something from C Shell and means to redirect both 1 and 2 file descriptor, ie same as `> file 2>&1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redirection operators aren't arguments that get passed to the kernel.
They're a shell language feature.

`< /input/1.txt`  or more explicitly `0</input/1.txt` means approximately (report errors according to your own preferences):

```
int fd;
if(0>(fd=open("/input/1.txt",O_RDONLY))){ perror("open"); /*...*/ }
if(0>dup2(fd,0)){ perror("dup"); /*...*/ }
if(fd!=0) close(fd);
```

while `&>/stdout/1.txt` or more POSIXly/explictly `1> /stdout/1.txt 2>&1` means

```
// 1> /stdout/1.txt
if(0>(fd=open("/stdout/1.txt",O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC))){ perror("open"); /*...*/ }
if(0>dup2(fd,1)){ perror("dup"); /*...*/ }
if(fd!=1) close(fd);

// 2>&1
if(0>dup2(1,2)){ perror("dup"); /*...*/ }
```

Comment: Thank you @PSkocik